# Is there an efficient way to store a lookup structure that uses random integer keys?

Tags: data-structures, persistence

I need to implement a lookup structure with the following requirements:

- Keys are random 128-bit integers
- Values are 64-bit
- It will be stored on disk
- It must be searchable without the entire structure being resident in memory (I intend to memory map the file)
- It must be mutable, but writes to disk must be incremental (must not require overwriting the entire structure)

Is there an efficient way to achieve all of this?

Please do not answer, "Don't use UUIDs." I am asking a specific question; changing the requirements changes the question.

Comment: It sounds like you're describing a database management system. Have you considered lightweight DBMS software such as SQLite? https://www.sqlite.org/index.html

Comment: If you can't or don't want to use off-the-shelf software, you can implement a B-Tree on disk: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree.

Comment: I have considered an RDBMS, but there are some significant downsides, so I’m investigating other paths

Comment: I’ve looked at B-trees but I read that their performance can be rather suboptimal when using non-sequential (random) keys

Comment: You might also consider B+ Trees: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%2B_tree. "Suboptimal" or not, there are good reasons why modern databases and file systems use those data structures. I'd be interested in a reference to the "suboptimal" performance on non-sequential keys.

Comment: This article discusses using UUIDs in a database and claims “UUIDs degrade database performance.“ https://rclayton.silvrback.com/do-you-really-need-a-uuid-guid

Comment: Sometimes you have to balance your requirements. You've said that you must use UUIDs. But a longer random key is going to cost you when compared to a shorter sequential key. That doesn't invalidate the underlying data structure; it just means that you've selected a less-than-optimum key type. B-Tree will still be effective, and quite efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your keys and values each are a fixed number of bytes, you could implement a [hashtable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hashtable) as a file. The first few bytes contain the current number of elements and the current capacity, and then the entries each take up 16 + 8 bytes (if 0 is forbidden as a key) or 1 + 16 + 8 bytes if you need a flag to indicate whether an entry exists or not.

You can hash the key, then use arithmetic to seek to the correct position in the file, then read or write just the entries you need to. To resolve hash collisions, [linear probing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_probing) is probably best to avoid the number of seeks. Since the keys are random, catastrophic collision pileups shouldn't happen, and the hash can simply be to take the lowest *k* bits of the key, where the current capacity is 2^*k*.

This takes O(*n*) space, and allows lookups in O(1) average time, and writes in O(1) amortized time. Occasionally, you have to resize the hashtable to increase the capacity on a write; this takes O(*n*) time on those occasions.

If you need O(1) writes in the worst-case, you could maintain both the old and new hashtables, do lookups in both, and then on each write operation, copy across two entries from the old to the new. If the capacity is always increased by a factor of 2, then this gives non-amortized constant time writes, except for the cost of allocating an empty hashtable of size O(*n*). If creating an empty file of a particular size is also too slow for a single write operation, then you can amortize empty-file-creation across many writes too.